# Pass a filename found in awk into vim command

Tags: bash, vim, awk, forever

`Forever` (a process manager for nodejs) gives new random logs each time you restart it.

I'm able to get the log filename with this command:

```
$ forever list | grep coffee | awk '{print $8}'
/home/vagrant/.forever/ZZRW.log
```

I'd like to be able to pass this filename into a vim command, so vim ends up executing:

```
vim /home/vagrant/.forever/ZZRW.log
```

And I'd like to alias this in my `.bash_profile` to be something like:

```
alias vimforeverlog="vim ???? forever list | grep coffee | awk '{print $8}'"
```

Any ideas?  I feel like I'm just missing a basic feature of pipes.

Comment: Try piping the output to the `xargs` command.  Something like `xargs -n1 vim`.

Comment: @EricJablow this will "work" with vim warning. also it could destroy  prompt with some terminal.

Comment: btw, the `grep` in your command could be saved: e.g `forever list|awk '/coffee/{print $8}'`

Comment: Kent, you're right.  I opened a security hole there.

Comment: Forever adds color to my output, so I also had to remove the color with this: `sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
vim $(forever list | grep coffee | awk '{print $8}')
```

should do the job, same as opening result from `find` in vim.

Comment: And good luck, @civilian, getting that into an alias. Use a function: `function vimforeverlog { vim "$(forever list | grep coffee | awk '{print $8}')"; }`

Answer (score 2):

```
forever list | grep coffee | awk '{print $8}' | xargs vim
```

xargs takes the output of the last command and appends it to the command line